# How to select data between two dates in sql?

Tags: java, oracle

How can i select a data in a table between two timestamp using java or sql but the range should be the currentime + 15 minutes.

If the currentime is 01:00:00, the data should be between 01:00:00 and 01:15:00 And i want to store the currentime in a variable.

ex: Mytable

```
Id name    Address   date
10 John    Florida   2014-05-02 00:00:00,123456
20 Smith   London    2014-05-02 01:00:00,123456
30 Jenny   Brighton  2014-05-02 01:10:00,123456
40 Benny   Yorkdale  2014-05-02 01:15:00,123456
```

Thank y

Comment: So you want to pick all records that are between currentTime and (currentTime+15 minutes)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM MYTABLE
WHERE MYDATE BETWEEN SYSTIMESTAMP AND SYSTIMESTAMP + INTERVAL'15' MINUTE
```

`SYSTIMESTAMP` gives you the current time and checking it with Adding `INTERVAL` of 15 minutes to it.

Comment: Ok but SYSTIMESTAMP + INTERVAL '15' MINUTE will give me in the future and it's not possible, so my question is how to select data between currentTime-15 minutes and currentTime?

Comment: Just reverse the parameters, like `SYSTIMESTAMP - INTERVAL'15' MINUTE AND SYSTIMESTAMP`

Comment: Thank you for this , if i want to delete the data i try this but it's not working delete FROM MYTABLE WHERE name =( select name from (select name where address= 'Florida') AND Date BETWEEN systimestamp - INTERVAL '15' MINUTE AND SYSTIMESTAMP)

Comment: When you use `=` , it has to be with _one_ row only. In this case, may be more than one row is returned and hence you  need to use `IN`

Comment: ok there is a missing colunm in my table i forgot to add Company which is same for all person and in my previous sql command if i change the address by Company = IBM, it s still not working, ERROR : "FROM keyword not found where expected"